# Server 2016 SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having trouble searching the answer for this.  I think it's the phrasing I'm using. I'll just describe my scenario.

Writing a simple Select statement.

```sql
select Lastname, FirstName, Department, EmployeeID, CardholderStatus, CardholderExpireDate
from dbo.Cardholders
order by LastName
```

The cardholderStatus field displays a numerical value, 0,1,0r 2

I wanted to define the value in the select statement for output so that it is in a more readable format for the person the report is going to.

0 = Inactive.
1 = Active.
2 = Date.

How would I write that part of the statement?

Comment: You can use case statement:
CASE cardholderStatus 
WHEN 0 THEN 'Inactive'
WHEN 1 THEN 'Active'
WHEN 2 THEN 'Date'
END as Desctiption

Comment: You might do this in code - but what will you do when you write yet another statement that also needs to decode the value? Typically you create a lookup table for this and then join when needed. You could also create a view for this purpose or add a computed column to the table.

Comment: Thank you all, the case statement worked

Answer (score 0):

This should match your need:

```
SELECT Lastname, FirstName, Department, EmployeeID, CardholderStatus, CardholderExpireDate, 

CASE WHEN cardholderStatus = 0 THEN 'Inactive'
WHEN cardholderStatus = 1 THEN 'Active'
ELSE 'Date'
END AS cardholderStatusAsText 

FROM dbo.Cardholders ORDER BY LastName
```